# MYSQL get last date from table that has not yet passed

Tags: mysql, sql, date

In my database in table_a every row has a date_created like "2011-04-17"

Now some of these dates are in the past, but my question is how can I retrieve the latest date that has not yet passed?

Comment: Take into account that NOW() and CURDATE() return the time (and date) value in local timezone of the server, if that is an issue for you, use UTC_TIMESTAMP() and convert it into a date in the timezone you wish using CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 'UTC', ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM table_a  WHERE CURDATE() <= date_created
```

[**CURDATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)

> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD
>   format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or
>   numeric context.

Comment: wow, so easy :p thx m8 this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE date_created >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

IF date_created is a date datatype then you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE date_created >= NOW()
LIMIT 1
```